# Clean way for flashing factory image on Samsung Galaxy Nexus?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, 4.1-jelly-bean, fastboot

Is this the correct and clean way for flashing factory Jelly Bean image on Samsung Galaxy Nexus, **without using any external tool** (apart from Android SDK)?

I don't want to to break my phone, so I'm asking this. I've collected these informations from various sources, but I need a confirm that all the steps and commands are correct and needed.

---

**Step 1**: Download and install [Android SDK for Windows](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). Start Android SDK manager, select *Android SDK platform-tools* and *Google USB Driver* (this should be already selected) and install. It will take a while.

After packages installation, add the folder:

```
C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
```

to your PATH variable, to make command `fastboot` available in command prompt.

**Step 2**: Download a factory image from official [Factory Images for Nexus Devices](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images). For me is "yakju" for Galaxy Nexus "maguro" (GSM/HSPA+), file [yakju-jro03c-factory-3174c1e5.tgz](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/yakju-jro03c-factory-3174c1e5.tgz)

Make a new folder, say C:\jro03c. Open yakju-jro03c-factory-3174c1e5.tgz and extract bootloader-maguro-primelc03.img along with radio-maguro-i9250xxlf1.img to C:\jro03c. Folder now contains two image files:

```
C:\jro03c\bootloader-maguro-primelc03.img
C:\jro03c\radio-maguro-i9250xxlf1.img
```

Then inside the .tgz file itself, open image-yakju-jro03c.zip and copy all *.img files to C:\jro03c. You will end up with six image files:

```
C:\jro03c\boot.img
C:\jro03c\bootloader-maguro-primelc03.img
C:\jro03c\radio-maguro-i9250xxlf1.img
C:\jro03c\recovery.img
C:\jro03c\system.img
C:\jro03c\userdata.img
```

**Step 3**: Power off your Galaxy Nexus. Press and hold Volume Up and Volume Down then press and hold the Power button; the Galaxy Nexus will now enter "fastboot mode". Connect your phone using the USB cable.

Then open a command prompt (Windows Key + R opens "Run", then type in `cmd`) type:

```
cd C:\jro03c
fastboot oem unlock
fastboot reboot-bootloader
fastboot flash bootloader bootloader-maguro-primelc03.img
fastboot reboot-bootloader
fastboot flash radio radio-maguro-i9250xxlf1.img
fastboot reboot-bootloader
fastboot flash system system.img
fastboot flash userdata userdata.img
fastboot flash boot boot.img
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
fastboot reboot-bootloader
fastboot erase cache
fastboot oem lock
fastboot reboot
```

Comment: You should note that `fastboot oem unlock` wipes the device, and should be used only if necessary (if you haven't unlocked the bootloader before). For this reason, I'd suggest to leave the bootloader unlocked (i.e. remove `fastboot oem lock` from the list of commands).

Comment: @onik you're perfectly right, but for the warranty to apply I think that bootloader should remain locked. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, that's right, but you can always lock it, but since unlocking wipes the device I prefer to keep it unlocked in case I need to flash the device.

Comment: For linux users, the factory image download includes a shell script that includes all the steps necessary for a re-flash. Take a look and see if there is an equivalent batch file for Windows users.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the correct and official way of flashing

Be aware though, that no matter which way you flash, you can still break your phone

For example, you're in the middle of flashing your device, and the USB lead comes out - bricked device.

Or you're flashing, and you have a powercut - bricked device.

So, the moral is that there is no completely 100% safe way of flashing a device.