# Flashing Galaxy Nexus with radio band

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, rom-flashing, radio-firmware

I'm trying the steps in [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/29421/981)
to flash a factory image on my Galaxy nexus. Once I install Android SDK for Windows, I then:

- Open the SDK Android manager .exe
- Install SDK platform-tools since Google USB Driver doesn't appear

After that

- `C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools`

When I get there I can only see `C:\Users\AppData\Local\`; there is no Android folder.

Also can I use any other radio.img in the process?

- I downloaded the image from google page, filename called `yakju-jop40d-factory-279cdc5d.tgz` (for GSM radio)
- I am located in Central America having network signal issues.
- And finally, I am running a custom ROM with ClockworkMod recovery.

I'm stuck and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Read... `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools` where `<Username>` is your Windows user id.. did you check in there... I think you've mis-read that bit

Comment: Is it really necessary to flash a radio baseband despite "having network signal issues"? That could be provider problem, please clarify exactly what is wrong there. You may not need to do that at all...

Comment: Hi! Tom yes I did that app data folder in windows is hidden so I make sure is my Windows Profile  no luck my cell phone is not plug in

Comment: Ok this is what happen I have  some signal on several areas so while searching found several basaband radio you can test with them to get better signal

Comment: Sometimes I get no mobile network available and no signal bar I have 3 different sim card with different providers and is the same some of them vary with the signal of course that's why I'm trying to follow this steps to do a full and clean up installation with Android SDK for windows I'm using windows 7 64 bits enterprise.